# Formatting with \t with unknown string lengths in C#

Tags: c#, format

This might be a hard question, or a stupidly simple one. Either way, bear with me, as I'm quite new to `C#`.

I've been building a `Form` with a `ListBox` inside, and a few other things, and all has been well. Where things get odd are in the filling of said box with information.

My logic to filling this `ListBox` thus far has been:

```
foreach (var value in userList)
{
    listBoxForForm.Items.Add("#" + value.internalId + " \t\t-\t" + value.title + "\t\t-\t" + value.typeName);
}
```

(Don't mind the odd  between the `"` and the `\t`!)

The problem is that this looks odd if certain values are too long (not "long" as in `value.length` but "long" as in width).

To better explain it, I took a screenshot (forgive the government-style censoring):

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that the text doesn't seem to format correctly when using `\t` in this context.

Is there a way I can format this text neatly in the intended 3-column style I'm going for here? Without knowing the length of the variables in each `value`, I mean?

Comment: It does *exactly* what you've asked it to do :)

Comment: @Thomas 100% true. I just don't know how to phrase what I ACTUALLY want it to do ;)

Comment: Why aren't you using some sort of grid control in your UI?

Comment: If you need multiple columns use a `ListView` or `DataGridView`.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for being slow, yes, yes it very much did! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with [String.PadLeft()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main()
    {   
        string s = "cat".PadRight(10);  string s2 = "poodle".PadRight(10);
        Console.Write(s);   
        Console.WriteLine("feline");    
        Console.Write(s2);  
        Console.WriteLine("canine");
    }
}
```

which will output:

```
cat       feline
poodle    canine
```

Comment: Only works in an SO code block, he's using a variable-pitch font. And of course still doesn't work when the padding is less than the phrase width, the problem he has now, he might as well use the  ListBox.CustomTabOffsets property.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using tabs, you should use a `String.PadRight(X)` where X is the maximum length of the field.  You will need to ensure that your X value is longer than the maximum length of the data, or clip the data to the maximum length to ensure that the columns line up.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

String.PadRight and String.PadLeft Methods